# Run npm as superuser, it isn't a good idea?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting errors with `npm` while trying to install/update packages without SU permissions on Linux.

The *easy* way to solve the problem is execute `sudo npm install <package>`, but I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

Best way is to become the owner of `.npm` folder, as I found into StackOverflow's questions and blog posts.

My question is: why run `npm` as SU it isn't a good idea?

Comment: becouse it lets you to execute/read/write with superuser privileges, so If sth exploits your npm process it can execute/read/write as a SU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `npm` as a super user has a risk of running some untrusted code as a super user which can potentially mess with your entire system. Running `npm` as an unprivileged user has a risk of running that code with less privileges and it won't be able to mess with the entire system - just with your own files (which can be equally bad, depending on how you look at it).

What I often do and recommend is to install Node in your home directory instead of globally on the system if it's your own computer. That way you don't have to run with `sudo` or `su` for `npm` or even for `make install` of Node itself.

I run a lot of versions of Node that I compile from sources sometimes with different switches and the convention that I use is to install Node in versioned directories, either globally in `/opt` (but then you need `sudo`) or locally in my home directory in `~/opt`.

I do it like this:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.1.0/node-v7.1.0.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-v7.1.0.tar.gz
cd node-v7.1.0
./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/node-v7.1.0
make && make test && make install
```

Then I create a symlink `~/opt/node` pointing to `~/opt/node-v7.1.0` and I have:

```
PATH="$HOME/opt/node/bin:$PATH"
```

in my `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

That way I don't have to run as super user for installing Node or for running npm.

As a bonus I can quickly switch my default Node version just by changing the symlink, and at any time I can run any other version if I change the PATH or run Node with a full path like `~/opt/node-v7.0.0/bin/node`.

I explained that installation process in more detail in my other answers:

- [node 5.5.0 already installed but node -v fetches with “v4.2.1” on OS X & homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180505/node-5-5-0-already-installed-but-node-v-fetches-with-v4-2-1-on-os-x-homebre/37181311#37181311)
- [NodeJS API with external deps in other language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635325/nodejs-api-with-external-deps-in-other-language/39636517#39636517)

I don't want to go into too much detail here since this answer is about why running `npm` as a superuser is not a good idea - this installation process is just one solution to not have to run `npm` as a superuser.

Other options of setting your npm permissions to avoid running as a superuser are described in [Fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) in npm docs (thanks to RyanZim for pointing it out in the comments).

Comment: Good explanation of why you shouldn't use `sudo` when running `npm`. Perhaps the answer would be more complete if it linked to https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions?

Comment: Great explanation!

Comment: @RyanZim Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my answer.