# Node installed but node cannot be found in Ubuntu VPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nvm

I installed node via NVM. I installed node 0.10.32. using NVM 0.25.0

When I do `node -v` I get

```
-bash: /root/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

when I do `npm v` I get

```
/root/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/npm: 2: exec: /root/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/node: not found
```

All those directories exist and node executable is in it but they are reading as not found. Node seems to be installed but I am unable to use it. I am not sure how to fix this issue. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Comment: 1. Where is the `node` executable on the system? E.g., where do you actually see `node` not as a hardlink/symlink? 2. Is that directory shown when you do `echo $PATH`?

Comment: if I go to the directory "/root/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/" there is "node" in there. Also when I echo $PATH I get /root/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: The first path is the nvm, node path, let me know if I did not completely answer your question @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0):

Check that your ~/.bash_profile has this:

export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm

source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/576

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things can be wrong here from what you describe. Generally I don't recommend using nvm to install Node on servers. It works fine for your own work on a local machine but when you need to be sure what is installed and where, I recommend doing a real installation.

I recently wrote a tutorial on how to install Node on Linux:

- https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a

It is specifically about version 6.7.0 but just change the version number to use any other version of Node.

You can see other answers showing how to install Node properly and troubleshoot if it isn't installed correctly:

- [Run npm as superuser, it isn't a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525238/run-npm-as-superuser-it-isnt-a-good-idea/40525676#40525676)
- [node 5.5.0 already installed but node -v fetches with "v4.2.1" on OS X & homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180505/node-5-5-0-already-installed-but-node-v-fetches-with-v4-2-1-on-os-x-homebre/37181311#37181311)

Just get the binary or source package of the version that you need, install it where you want and it will work. The most reliable way is to install a source package because you can run `make test` before you install and because `npm` will have the correct shebang line (which may not always be the case with binary distribution - which, incidentally, is also used by nvm). No need to use nvm or any other tool to do that.

The nvm is great if you need to quickly switch Node versions during development on your local machine but if you want a reliable way to install Node on the server then it's best to install it normally.