# A package I install using npm -g it doesn't show up in a bash script, why?

Tags: node.js, linux, git, bash, knex.js

I have this `post-receive` script as a git hook when exporting with the following contents

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export NODE_ENV=production
git --work-tree=/home/myusername/app --git-dir=/home/myusername/git checkout -f
cd /home/myusername/app
npm prune
npm install --production
knex migrate:latest
```

When ssh'd in my server I installed knex globally but it doesn't seem to exist within the bash shell's environment. I lack the knowledge of knowing how they are different. I also noticed my node versions were different. How do I import my user's normal environment?

Answer (score 1):

To get the names and versions of modules that you have installed globally run:

```
npm list --global --depth=0
```

You can then install those modules on the second system with:

```
npm install --global module_name module_name ...
```

If you want to install a specific version of Node on the second system you can use `nvm` or see those answers for details:

- [Run npm as superuser, it isn't a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525238/run-npm-as-superuser-it-isnt-a-good-idea/40525676#40525676)
- [node 5.5.0 already installed but node -v fetches with "v4.2.1" on OS X & homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180505/node-5-5-0-already-installed-but-node-v-fetches-with-v4-2-1-on-os-x-homebre/37181311#37181311)
- [Node installed but node cannot be found in Ubuntu VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723668/node-installed-but-node-cannot-be-found-in-ubuntu-vps/40724019#40724019)

This is the first time I see a shebang like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

I've seen using `/usr/bin/env` to find `node`, `python`, `perl` interpreters etc. but never for `bash`. Usually it's just:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Remember that if you want to run some program from a Bash script (without giving a full path) then it must be in a directory that is in the PATH environment variable.

To see your PATH run:

```
echo $PATH
```

Or you can use a full path to a binary in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/full/path/to/something
```

and then it doesn't need to be in the PATH.

Comment: What I didn't know is that -g installs it in the node version that youre using. I was using nvm on my server and it got installed under the version I was using. Sourcing nvm in my bash script and then specifying the node version I wanted to use before trying to run knex solved my issue.

Comment: @MathieuBertin Yes, that's how nvm works. You didn't mention that you use nvm on the server.

Comment: I lacked the proper understanding of how npm install -g worked. Thank you for your detailed answer.