# How to host web application on remote host

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-applications, remote-server

I am currently using nodejs + express js.
web application is hosted on express js on port 1234.
at present with local host things are working fine. Code is in git repository. If i have a remote server, then how to package the web application and start the web application on remote server. We are not using tom cat. is there any way i build/package the entire application into jar and place it in remote server and start the web application? how to give a domain name rather than IP address in URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312651/how-to-run-node-js-on-dedicated-server

Comment: i am new to express js. Can anyone please help by give by step by step procedures to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

- [how to run node js on dedicated server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312651/how-to-run-node-js-on-dedicated-server/41313267#41313267)

I cannot mark this question as the duplicate of the one above because the original poster of that question didn't accept the answer, but the question was answered and you can find info there.

Some more info on:

- [Installing Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180505/node-5-5-0-already-installed-but-node-v-fetches-with-v4-2-1-on-os-x-homebre/37181311#37181311)
- [Running Node on servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635325/nodejs-api-with-external-deps-in-other-language/39636517#39636517)